# Express js serve static files not working with nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am getting confused as to why my latest web app cannot get any of the css or js files I have included. On my local machine, the files come over fine but when I host it on my nginix fronted server I am getting 404's. Here is my html includes.

```
<!-- ANGULAR -->
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR BOOTSTRAP UI -->
<script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR ROUTE-->
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- ANGULAR APP SETUP -->
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>

<!-- Custom styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Here is the node express server code

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                        // create our app w/ express
var morgan = require('morgan');                  // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');         // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var path = require('path');

// configuration =================

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
console.log("DIRECTORY= "+path.join(__dirname, '/public'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

app.get('/DI_Uploader/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

//decides between what heroku would give it or our own chosen port for a locally hosted solution
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8002));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I have all of my js/css/bower_components under the public directory. The only other thing I can think the issue is nginx where I have this...

```
location /DI_Uploader/ {

    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass http://webserverName:8002;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

The only other thing different about the hosted version vs my local version is that to get to the hosted version I am going to http://website.com/DI_Uploader/ instead of the root website.com. Any direction is helpful since I am still fairly new with express.

EDIT: removed periods in front of html includes

Didn't know how to put this in a comment but here is the folder structure on the web server.

```
- DI_Uploader
    - node_modules
    - public
        - bower_components
        - css
        - js
        index.html
    server.js
    package.json
```

Comment: Why are you starting ANY paths for resources in your web page with `./`?  That makes the browser interpret them relative to the path of the web page which is almost NEVER what you want.  Client paths should usually start with just `/`.

Comment: Now that I see that the hosted version makes all paths start with `http://website.com/DI_Uploader/`, then my previous comment may explain your entire issue.  That means that a request for `./css/styles.css` in the browser will arrive to your server as a request for `/DI_Uploader/css/styles.css` which is not what you are set up for.

Comment: @jfriend00 Honestly I just have always done that and it has worked out for me so far. I have corrected that but still having this issue explained. I will update the question with this as well.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think this was also allowing me to get the static content from within DI_Uploader. The folder stucture is DI_Uploader then inside it public then inside that all the html,css,js. When I remove the ./ I am now requesting website.com/css rather than website.com/DI_Uploader/css which I don't think is correct either.

Comment: But, you're pointing `express.static()` directly at `public` so it doesn't matter what's above that in the disk hierarchy, right?  When your client requests `/js/app.js`, where exactly is that file on your hard drive?  Is it `public/js/app.js`? where `public` is `path.join(__dirname, '/public')`?

Comment: Please put folder structure in your question where you can properly format it.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah I just figured that out. I understand how setting the public is going against what I am doing. So essentially I have static content at http://webserver.com/DI_Uploader/public/css/styles.css and I am not sure how to link to it from the front end knowing just that public wasn't supposed to be there in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jfriend00, I was able to see that the reason I couldn't get my static content to load was because I had set static on the root of the website when I really needed it on my nested /DI_Uploader/ folder. To fix this you can use virtual paths to trick it.

See http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

code changed to be

```
app.use('/DI_Uploader',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Comment: So you want `/DI_Uploader/` to be in the URLs that are requested?  Very confused.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need DI_Uploader in the url in order for nginx to pick it up and direct it to the correct node js express instance. This server is also hosting two other webservers being another express instance and a tomcat instance. We are trying to not have to create another dns record/VIP for the correct port. We are only doing this so we don't have to wait on the networking team here.
TLDR: yes

Comment: I am able to redirect to the correct route in express and server the html file (app.use(./dev',...) , but my style sheets in the public dir still do not load